# Why does this program not turn my bitmap 90 degrees?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code should rotate an image 90 degrees, but it isn't working.  Instead, all i get on my screen after running is grey pixels and one line of the original pixels at the bottom. Any ideas about what I have done wrong in this code?

```
  void rotate90(Image& image)
    {
        Pixel * tempPixel = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
        int tempWidth = image.infoHeader.biWidth;
        for(int r = 0; r < image.infoHeader.biHeight; r ++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < image.infoHeader.biWidth; c++)
            {

                int f = c+(r*image.infoHeader.biWidth);
                int t = (image.infoHeader.biHeight - r) + (image.infoHeader.biWidth-1);
                tempPixel[t] = image.pixels[f];
            }
        }

        delete[] image.pixels;
        image.pixels=tempPixel ;
    }
```

My updated code as of by comment below

```
void rotate90(Image& image)
{
    Pixel * tempPixel = new Pixel[(image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight)];
    int tempWidth = image.infoHeader.biWidth;
    image.infoHeader.biWidth = image.infoHeader.biHeight;
    image.infoHeader.biHeight = tempWidth;
    for(int r = 0; r < image.infoHeader.biHeight; r ++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < image.infoHeader.biWidth; c++)
        {

            int f = c+(r*image.infoHeader.biWidth);
            int t = (image.infoHeader.biHeight-r-1) +(image.infoHeader.biWidth * ((4 * image.infoHeader.biWidth * image.infoHeader.biHeight) % 4));
            tempPixel[t] = image.pixels[f];
        }
    }

    delete[] image.pixels;
    image.pixels=tempPixel ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `c` in the calculation of the new position `t`. It should be multiplying the width I guess

Comment: Also note that it shouldn't be multiplying by biWidth but by biWidth times the number of bytes per pixel, rounded up to the nearest multiple of 4.

Comment: Ok i did that and now i get a bunch of the pixels just jumbled everywhere.

Comment: @Jake, your update is even further away from correct. I'd suggest reading this answer carefully and thinking hard about the memory layout and how to express it in a formula.

Comment: The number of bytes being height*width?